# Uniting two SQLs with group & count under different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I have DB of stores, each belonging to a retailer. I want to get a list of retailers with the respective number of stores, serving a specific product, and ordered by country.

So, looking for the number of stores selling tools per retailer, I have the following query:

```
select r.country, r.name, count(s.id) AS count from retailer r
JOIN store s ON r.id = s.retailer_id
JOIN product p ON p.store_id = s.id
WHERE p.product = 'tools'
GROUP BY r.country, r.name
ORDER BY r.country;
```

and get a list like

```
DE Aldi                 915
UK Aldi                 576
US King Kullen          824
US Walmart             1280
```

Now I do the same query for 'toys' instead of 'tools' and get a list with different counts:

```
DE Aldi                 703
UK Aldi                 222
US Walmart             1560
```

assuming that King Kullen does not sell toys anywhere, so it is not listed.

How can I get a united list for tools+toys?

```
DE Aldi                 915   703
UK Aldi                 576   222
US King Kullen          824     0
US Walmart             1280  1560
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select r.country, r.name, 
       sum(case when p.product = 'tools' then 1 else 0 end) as num_tools
       sum(case when p.product = 'toys' then 1 else 0 end) as num_toys
from retailer r join
     store s 
     on r.id = s.retailer_id join
     product p 
     on p.store_id = s.id
where p.product in ('tools', 'toys')
group by r.country, r.name
order by r.country;
```

Note:  The `where` clause is not strictly needed.  However, it can improve performance.

EDIT:

You can incorporate count distinct as:

```
       count(distinct case when p.product = 'tools' then s.id end) as num_tools
       count(distinct case when p.product = 'toys' then s.id end) as num_toys
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well in principal. However, a problem remains.

I have subcategories of tools. p.tools may have another . A store may sell house tools, or garden tools, or both, it does not matter - I need all the stores selling tools!

But with your "sum"

Comment: @KnightMove . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  Look at the `where` clause in the queries **you** wrote.  You can, of course, adjust the conditions so they are, say `product like '%tools%'` if that is what you really want.

Comment: Ctd: With your "sum" method, I count stores selling house and garden tools twice. How can I prevent this?

Comment: In my original query, the problem does not occur as I count the store IDs. I did not expect a solution could open up another problem. But ok, I will try to get a way outta here, although it does not seem easy. Thanks.

Comment: @KnightMove . . . This logic is equivalent to the query in your question.  I suspect that might not be the query you are actually running.

Comment: By now I know that in the original query I should have used 
`count(DISTINCT s.id)` instead of `count(s.id)`, and that my original search results were faulty. So you were right in every regard. 

Do you know an equivalent change in your suggested query?